# UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Использую простой конфиг вида:

```
  name:
    container_name: name
    build: dockerfile
    command: start app
    working_dir: ./dir
    volumes:
      - ./vol:vol
    env_file:
      - config
    networks:
      - a
```

В нем развернута `tensorflow` и простой контроллер на `python`.

И суть в том, что работает. Но на одной из машин, под `ubuntu 20.04` получаю вот эту ошибку:

```
ERROR: for name  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
```

С `--verbose`:

```
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: ServiceName(project='name', service='name', number=1)
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()

ERROR: for name  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
compose.parallel.parallel_execute_iter: Failed: <Service: name>
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()

ERROR: for name  UnixHTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=None): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_timeout_error: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
If you encounter this issue regularly because of slow network conditions, consider setting COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT to a higher value (current value: 60).
```

Главное, на более слабых, машинах работает... Даже на 2-ух ядрах. А, на 12-и - нет.
Конечно, докер на "проблемной" машине работает.

Comment: Проверял, сервис не работает, - контейнер не запускается. Самое любопытное, что после нескольких итераций down/up он запускается и работает.

Comment: Он не запускается вследствие возникновения этой ошибки, на одной из машин. На других он работает, исправно работает. На этой же "проблемной" машине тоже запускается после "проклацывания" docker-compose down/up. Раза с пятого, например.

Comment: И там запрос не делается. Там просто пишу: docker-compose up, где докер вываливает эту ерунду...

Comment: Это на моменте "аттача" к контейнеру.

Comment: Пробовали делать как в сообщении с ошибкой (добавлять `--verbose`)?

Comment: Запустил, добавил в ответ.

Comment: `compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()`, судя по всему - из-за этого проблема.

Comment: Рестарт точно не помогает. А вот таймауты - нужно проверить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что это [известная нерешенная](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3927) проблема.

Рекомендуют увеличить таймаут перед запуском:

```
export DOCKER_CLIENT_TIMEOUT=120
export COMPOSE_HTTP_TIMEOUT=120
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230536/docker-compose-up-times-out-with-unixhttpconnectionpool/63521316

Comment: Дико... Как на ноутбуке с 2-мя физическими и 4-мя логическими все работает, а на сервере, 12/24 - нет. Мб, что сервер - mac с убунтой.